# Hex float representation in c

Tags: c, floating-point, hex

When I am reading hex notation of floats in C then I encounter a special number "0xa.1fp10" from Stephen Prata book. When I assigned this number to a float or double variable and printed it using "%a" format specifier in `printf`, then the result was 0x1.43e000p+13 which do not match with the original. But both are same value 10364 in decimal.
What is going on? Why has output value changed? How can I get the original number as output?

Comment: As you've discovered, there are multiple possible representations of the same value.  C retains the value, not the representation.

Comment: But what is the standard representation?
And how I get original representation?

Comment: Just like (decimal format) 17.3e12 and 1.73e13 are the same number, but in your case, the difference is in hex, so not so obvious.

Comment: I am also unable to take input of floating point number in p notation using %a conversion specifier on Windows 10 system.What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you cannot portably get the *same* format `0xa.1fp10` out of `printf`. The C standard specifies that the output of `%a` is such that for a [**normal**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.3.5) double that is non-zero, there be *one* non-zero digit *before* the `.` and as many digits as needed to represent the value exactly *after* the `.`. The implementation can choose **how many of the first bits goes into the first digit!**

However C11 standard has footnote [278](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note278) that says that

> Binary implementations can choose the hexadecimal digit to the left of the decimal-point character so that subsequent digits align to nibble (4-bit) boundaries.

And here's the problem. Since IEEE 754 `double`s have 53-bit mantissas; the first bit being 1 for **normal** numbers; the rest of the 52 bits are equally divisible by 4, an implementation following that footnote (Glibc on my machine seems to be one), will *always* output any finite non-zero floating point number so that it starts with `0x1.`!

Try for example this minimal program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for (double i = 1; i < 1024 * 1024; i *= 2) {
        printf("%a %a %a\n", 1.0 * i, 0.7 * i, 0.67 * i);
    }
}
```

The output of which on my computer is

```
0x1p+0 0x1.6666666666666p-1 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p-1
0x1p+1 0x1.6666666666666p+0 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+0
0x1p+2 0x1.6666666666666p+1 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+1
0x1p+3 0x1.6666666666666p+2 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+2
0x1p+4 0x1.6666666666666p+3 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+3
0x1p+5 0x1.6666666666666p+4 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+4
0x1p+6 0x1.6666666666666p+5 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+5
0x1p+7 0x1.6666666666666p+6 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+6
0x1p+8 0x1.6666666666666p+7 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+7
0x1p+9 0x1.6666666666666p+8 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+8
0x1p+10 0x1.6666666666666p+9 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+9
0x1p+11 0x1.6666666666666p+10 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+10
0x1p+12 0x1.6666666666666p+11 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+11
0x1p+13 0x1.6666666666666p+12 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+12
0x1p+14 0x1.6666666666666p+13 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+13
0x1p+15 0x1.6666666666666p+14 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+14
0x1p+16 0x1.6666666666666p+15 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+15
0x1p+17 0x1.6666666666666p+16 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+16
0x1p+18 0x1.6666666666666p+17 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+17
0x1p+19 0x1.6666666666666p+18 0x1.570a3d70a3d71p+18
```

This output is *efficient* - for each **normal** number the code needs to output just `0x1.` followed by all of the actual nibbles of the mantissa converted to hex, strip trailing `0` characters and append `p+` followed by exponent.

---

For long doubles, the x86 format has **64** bit mantissa. Since 64 bits is exactly divisible into nibbles, a sensible implementation will have a *full* nibble preceding the `.` for **normal** numbers, with values varying from `0x8` to `0xF` (the first bit is always 1), and up to 15 nibbles following the point.

Try your implementation with

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    for (long double i = 1; i < 32; i ++) {
        printf("%La\n", i);
    }
}
```

to see if it conforms to this expectation...

---

Between positive normal numbers and zero there can be subnormal numbers - my Glibc represents these double values with `0x0.` followed by the actual nibbles of the mantissa, with trailing zeroes removed, and the fixed exponent `-1022` - again, the representation being that which is *easiest* to implement and fastest to compute.

Comment: I believe the asterisk was unintentional: `i < 1024* ;`

Comment: @user694733 intentional but missing the other 1024 there, idk where that went :D

Answer (score 1):

This is a hexadecimal floating-point format. The digits (and period) after `0x` and before `p` are a hexadecimal numeral. That part is called the significand. The digits after `p` are a decimal numeral indicates the power of 2 by which to multiply the significand.

In `0xa.1fp10`, the significand is `a.1f`. This represents the number 10•16<sup>0</sup> + 1•16<sup>−1</sup> + 15•16<sup>−2</sup>, which equals 10 + 31/256, or 2591/256.

Then `p10` says to multiply this by 2<sup>10</sup> = 1024, so the result is 2591/256 • 1024 = 10,364.

The result is only a number. `0xa.1fp10`, `10364`, and `0x1.43ep13` are three different numerals that represent the same number. When you store this value in a `float` or `double`, the object contains only the number. There is no record of its original format. When you print it with `%a`, the implementation chooses the leading digit<sup>1</sup>. Because there is no record of the original numeral, there is no way to cause `printf` to produce the original string, unless you have some separate record of this information and write your own software to print the numeral.

Floating-point formats often use a binary base, and it is difficult to write good software that correctly converts decimal scientific notation to binary floating-point. (It is a solved problem with published papers, but good software has not always been used.) Using a hexadecimal format instead of decimal makes it easy to exactly specify the value the author wants in the floating-point number and easy for the compiler to interpret it. The hexadecimal format is designed for this purpose: Ease and exactness of reading and writing floating-point numbers. It is not designed to facilitate aesthetic concerns such as reproducing a particular scaling or normalization.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> When `%a` is used, the C standard leaves it up to the implementation to choose the scaling used except that there is exactly one digit before the decimal-point character, it is non-zero if the number is in the normal range of the floating-point format, and the number of digits after the point equals the formatting precision.

Answer (score 1):

> But both are same value 10364 in decimal.

Indeed.

> What is going on? Why has output value changed?

Why *shouldn't* it change?  The representation of a `double` in memory does not carry any formatting information.  And as you yourself observed, the output represents the same number that the input did, so the value *did not* change.  It's just represented differently.

Roughly analogous behavior could be made to happen with decimal numbers, too, using `%e` directives.

> How can I get the original number as output?

Chances are good that you *cannot* get your particular `printf()` implementation to emit the particular representation the program read from its input.  However, if there is something systematic about that representation, such as having the least exponent that affords a single hex digit before the radix point, then you could, in principle, write your own output function that produces that representation.

In comments you add,

> But what is the standard representation?

There isn't one in the sense of a representation demanded by the C language standard.  The language requires only that the representation have exactly one hex digit before the radix point, and that it be nonzero if the number is normalized and itself nonzero.  That leaves four possibilities for most normalized floating-point numbers.